# Restoring database .bak file in Sql Server 2008 causes error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I tried to restore a sql server 2008 .bak file in my sql server 2008 database server. It gives me the error:

```
THE MEDIA FAMILY ON DEVICE 'c:\...\MSSQL\BACKUP\...BAK' IS INCORRECTLY FORMED. 
SQL SERVER CANNOT PROCESS THIS MEDIA FAMILY. 
RESTORE HEADER ONLY IS TERMINATING ABNORMALLY.
```

Answer (score 1):

see:

http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2010/06/restore-failed-for-server-restore.html

<strike>Most probably the SQL Server 2005 is also installed on your machine.
See [MS link for resolution.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/940801)</strike>

Comment: Did you site the correct link? The one you've given applies to "Microsoft Office Accounting Professional or Microsoft Office Accounting Express."

Comment: I have both Sql Server 2005 as well as Sql Server 2008 in my machine. Do you want me to install 2005 express edition ? Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Joel: sorry, I must have been sleeping here....You are correct, it was an invalid link.

Comment: @scott: no do not uninstall anything. I made a mistake in my answer. I will delete it.

Comment: @scott: see http://dotnetguts.blogspot.com/2010/06/restore-failed-for-server-restore.html

Answer (score 1):

Your backup file is not a SQL Server backup file, or is corrupted. Make sure you restore the correct file, or get yourself a new, uncorrupted, copy of the BAK file.